# Dask dataframe keeps throwing OutOfBoundsDatetime error inspite of converting to string

Tags: python, dask

**Dask dataframe keeps throwing OutOfBoundsDatetime error inspite of converting to string**
I'm trying to read a sql table which has different date columns. Some have values set to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. While using ddf.compute() it's throwing OutOfBoundsDatetime exception. Even casting to String doesn't work. Below is the code

```
ddf = read_sql_table(table_name='TABLE_NAME', con=conn, index_col='index')
ddf=ddf['transaction_end_date'].astype({'transaction_end_date':str})
ddf.compute()
```

**Getting the below error:**

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 23:59:59
```

**Note**: I want to retain all the Timestamp values.

Comment: Hi, does it work wit Pandas only? Would you be bale somehow to filter or transform the lines with this date?

Comment: I don't get such error in Pandas. Transform is a workaround but I would need to see if there is a way to resolve this.  For tables with huge volume of data having scenarios where chunk size is not an option, I need to use Dask for computing.

Comment: Could you give us a reproducer to try to figure out the issue?